# Variable length sequence to sequence autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a sequence to sequence autoencoder with variable length sequences of floating points.
I was wondering which of these implementations are correct:

```
seq_autoenc = Sequential()
seq_autoenc.add(Masking(mask_value=mask_value, input_shape=(None, inp_dim)))
seq_autoenc.add(LSTM(enc_len, return_sequences=True, implementation=implementation, name='encoder'))
seq_autoenc.add(LSTM(inp_dim, return_sequences=True, implementation=implementation, name='decoder'))
```

or

```
seq_autoenc = Sequential()
seq_autoenc.add(Masking(mask_value=mask_value, input_shape=(inp_max_len, inp_dim)))
seq_autoenc.add(cell(enc_len, implementation=implementation, name='encoder'))
seq_autoenc.add(RepeatVector(inp_max_len, name='repeater'))
seq_autoenc.add(cell(inp_dim, return_sequences=True, implementation=implementation, name='decoder'))
```

The problem with the last code is that the maximum length of sequences is not known and it will truncate some of sequences in the testing phase.

Another problem that I'm facing is that the range of `mask_value` is not available, is it possible to use `np.nan` or `np.inf` as the masking value?